# How to list authors' GitHub usernames with Git?

Tags: git, github

I am listing a git repo's authors, cloned from GitHub.
I would like to find out a user's GitHub user ID.

- How can I list user's with their GitHub IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Github is just some random site to host git repositories.

The site is completely independent of the repository hosted there.

The author or committer of some commit contained in a git repository is completely unrelated to any github user.

One commit might be part of many different repositories (each belonging to a different user) hosted at github. The author of a commit might not even have an account on github.

Therefore you really cannot relate a commit to a github user.

Comment: This is actually not entirely correct. If a GitHub user merges a pull request through GitHub, then their GitHub username is associated with the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

What @michas said is correct.

However you could write a script that parses the authors' usernames from the git repository (using `git log` etc.) and search these usernames in Github using the [Github's Search API](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users).

The results of this search would contain the IDs you want.

Comment: What @michas wrote is actually not entirely correct. If a GitHub user merges a pull request through GitHub, then their GitHub username is associated with the merge commit.